# how to add the dot (.) before the year in the chicago.bst file?

Tags: bibtex, chicago-style

how to add the dot (.) before the year (2012) in the chicago.bst file like below

Bergmann, H. and U. Stephan, (2012). Moving on from nascent entrepreneurship: measuring cross-national differences in the transition to new business ownership. Small Business Economics 41:945-959.

---

i have added the BIB entry below

```
@article{bs12,
author = {Bergmann, H. and U. Stephan},
title = {Moving on from nascent entrepreneurship: measuring cross-national 
         differences in the transition to new business ownership},
journal = {Small Business Economics},
volume = {41},
year = {2012},
pages = {945-959},
}

@article{bs12,
author = {Bergmann, H. and U. Stephan},
title = {Moving on from nascent entrepreneurship: measuring cross-national differences in the transition to new business ownership},
journal = {Small Business Economics},
volume = {41},
year = {2012},
pages = {945-959},
}

@ARTICLE{bgk10,
author = {Brinckmann, J. and D. Grichnik and D. Kapsa},
title = {Should entrepreneurs plan or just storm the castle? {A} meta-analysis on contextual factors impacrting the business planning-performance relationship in small firms},
journal = {Journal of Business Venturing},
volume = {25},
year = {2010},
pages = {24-40},
}
```

---

```
 \documentclass[openany]{now}
   \begin{document}

   \nocite{*}
   \bibliographystyle{chicago}
   \bibliography{sample-bib}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: The standard `chicago` bibliography style does *not*, by default, insert a comma between the final author name and the parenthesized year. Moreover, `chicago` style usually inserts a comma between the volume number and the page range. Your write-up, in contrast, suggests that you version of `chicago` (a) inserts a comma the name and the year and (b) uses a colon to separate the volume number and the page range. Are you working with a modified form of the `chicago` bibliography style? If so, this might seriously complicate modifying the file `chicago.bst`.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of focusing on rather minor aspects of how the bibliographic entries are formatted, you should focus on getting the bibliographic material correct. For instance, a quick check of the `Small Business Economics` journal website reveals that the article by Heiko Bergmann and Ute Stephan was published in 2013, *not* in 2012 as you appear to suggest. Speaking as a part-time, occasional advisor of doctoral students, I can reveal that I always strongly exhort my students to **make sure that the contents of the bibliography are correct**. Formatting is much less important!!

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal `.tex` file. It looks as though you want the `author-date` Chicago now (also) caters to. But the fomatting of the desired output is 'wrong' in a few respects. In addition to Mico's comments, the journal title is normally set in italics. What is the reference/styleguide you are following?

Comment: @jon I have aded MWE in the questin itself